# I was trying to scrape a website using beautiful soup

Tags: python, screen-scraping

When i printed a_tag which is a variable containing all a tags  it was showing href elements. But when i try to print a_tag.attrs['href'] ,it shows
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'.

Comment: The initialization for ```a_tag``` didn't work, so it doesn't contain anything leading to an error. I'd check the code that results in the variable ```a_tag```.

Comment: some minimum reproducible example would be a great thing to do